# Remove wrong matches by keypoint orientation

Tags: matlab, opencv, computer-vision

Given a calibrated stereo pair the following things are known:

- Camera Intrinsics
- Essential Matrix
- Relative transformation
- A set of keypoint matches (matches satisfy epipolar constraint)

I want to filter out wrong matches by "projecting" the orientation of one keypoint to the other image and compare it to the orientation of the matched keypoint.

My solution idea is the following:

Given the match (p1,p2) with orientation (o1,o2) I compute the depth z of p1 by triangulation. I know create a second point close to p1 shifted a few pixels towards the orientation vector p1' = p1 + o1. After that you compute the 3D point of p1' with z and project it back to image 2 yielding in p2'. The projected orientation is now o2 = p2'-p2.

Does that algorithm work? Are there better ways (for example using the essential matrix)?

Answer (score 4):

While your idea sounds very interesting at first, I don't think that it can work because your way of computing the depth of `p'` will inevitably lead to wrong keypoint orientations in the second image. Consider this example I came up with:

[image]

Assume that `p1` is reprojected to `Q`. Now, you said that since you can't know the depth of `p'_1`, you set it to `z`, thus back-projecting `p'_1` to `Q'`. However, imagine that the true depth that corresponds to `p'1` is the point shown in green, `Q_t`. In that case, the correct orientation in the the second image is `c-b`, while with your solution, we have computed `a-b`, which is a wrong orientation.

A better solution, in my opinion, is to fix the pose of one of the two cameras, triangulate all the matches that you have, and do a small bundle adjustment (preferably using a robust kernel) where you optimize all the points but only the non-fixed camera. This should take care of a lot of outliers. It will change your estimation of the Essential though, but I think it is probable that it will improve it.

**Edit:**

The example above used large distances for visibility, and made abstraction from the fact that `a,b` and `c` are not necessarily colinear. However, assume that `p'1` is close enough to `p1`, so that `Q'` is close to `Q`. I think we can agree that most of the matches that passed the test would be in a configuration similar to this:

[image]

In that case, `c` and `a` both lie on the epipolar line given by the projection of `Q'` and camera center `1` in camera 2. But, `b` is not on that line (it is on the epipolar line corresponding to `Q`). So, the vectors `a-b` and `c-b` will be different by some angle.

But there are also two other issues with the method, that are related to this question: how do you determine the size of the vector `o1`? I assume that it will be a good idea to define it as `some_small_coef*(1/z)`, because `o1` will need to be smaller for distant objects. So, the two  other problems are

- if you are in an urban settings with for example, buildings that are a bit far, `z` grows, and the size of `o1` will need to be smaller than the width of one pixel.
- Assuming you overcome that problem, then the value of `some_small_coef` will need to be determined separately for different image couples (what if you go from indoors to outdoors?).

Comment: Your example is correct but it should be very unlikely that this happens in actual images. Let's assume Q_t is the real point and p'1 was close enough to p1 so that there is a connection between Q and Q_t (for example a surface). That would mean camera 1 sees the surface (Q_t,Q) from the right side and camera 2 sees the surface from the left side. I don't think such a feature match would pass the typical tests (ratio test+thresholding). Edit: Also my assumption is that keypoints can be seen as planar discs (or quads).

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I intially had thought of a more realistic counter-example, but ommited it for visibility. I edited the answer to discuss that more genreal example. Furthermore, I thought about two other issues that might interest you.

Comment: @dari Btw I'd really like to know what you thought of the edits. Especially in the case that you find them weak/wrong, I'd really appreciate it if you could give and explanation to correct me. But of course I'll understand if you don't have time. Thanks!

Comment: I think the magnitude of `o1` isn't really a problem because feature descriptors (like sift) usally sample a quad of radius 16 or larger around the keypoint. For larger scales this radius will even be bigger compared to the initial resolution, so chosing the size to be something smaller than the radius should be fine.

Comment: My current thoughts are that my algorithm is wrong, because the orientation in the second image depends on the surface normal and estimating the normal to be perpendicular to camera 1 (same z value) does not work.

Comment: For a solution i think that all possible ellipses (defined by the surface normal and projection to image 1) project the orientation vector to a cone in the second image (of like 120 degrees). So an outlier check should be possible if the second orientation is not in that cone.